# In WP after succesfully created a CPT, when i want to add new items i cannot find DIVI page template

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm a newbies regarding WP and i'm trying to learn by myself. But now i would like to have your help please.

i'm using the DIVI theme. I succesfully, ithink, created a CPT (i did it manually), i named it 'Restaurant'. When i want to 'add a new item' then the interface is very different.
[see Pic][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/drh7C.jpg

But for example if i use the native CPT in DIVI named 'Projects' then when i add a new item, i can see the builder for DIVI.

My question is how can i make it appear the same way when i add a new item in my CPT 'Restaurants'.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you are using premium DIVI theme then there is plugin called Divi booster available.
You can just go to the settings available in the **Divi Builder > Standard Builder->enable divi builder on custom post type**

just enable above option and it will show divi builder for your custom CPT also